# Application.ExecutablePath returns different casing

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

recently I stumbled upon this:

In my app I'm using `Application.ExecutablePath`. Interestingly its return value seems not to be consistent. If I start the app directly it returns `D:/path/to/app.exe`, but if I start it using the debugger it returns `D:/path/to/app.EXE`.

It is not an actual problem, because I can use `ToLower()` and do what I want.

But I was wondering if anyone knows a reasonable explanation for this behaviour, as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25773236/2925238) it seems not the only inconsistancy with `Application.ExecutablePath`.

Thanks

Comment: Windows doesnt care for casing..

Comment: I know, but the question remains, why the exact same function should return different values

Comment: It probably reflects what the path was when used to start the process, in other words, the debugger told Windows to start app.EXE.